# Combine multiple widgets into one in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I'm repeatedly using a pair of `QComboBox` and `QListWidget` in a project. Their interaction is highly coupled - when an item is selected in the combo box, the list is filtered in some way. I'm copy pasting all the signal and slot connections between these two widgets across multiple dialog box implementation which I don't think is a good idea.

Is it possible to create a custom widget, which will hold these two widgets and will have all signal and slot connection in one place? Something like as follows:

```
class CustomWidget
{
    QComboBox combo;
    QListWidget list;

    ...
};
```

I want to use this widget as a single widget.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to sub-class `QWidget` (or `QFrame`).

```
class CustomWidget: public QWidget {
 Q_OBJECT

 CustomWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent) {
    combo = new QComboBox(...);
    list  = new QListWidget(...);
    // create the appropriate layout
    // add the widgets to it
    setLayout(layout);
 }

 private:
  QComboBox *combo;
  QListWidget *list;

};
```

Handle all the interactions between the list and the combo in that custom widget (by connecting the appropriate signals to the appropriate slots, possibly defining your own slots for this).

You then expose your custom widget's behavior/API through dedicated signals and slots, possibly mimicking the ones in the list and/or the combo.

The [Address book](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/tutorials-addressbook.html) tutorial walks you through all of that, including creating a custom widget and defining signals and slots for it.

Comment: I read through the address book example you linked in your reply and I've got one question that bugs me: Why aren't all the `new`ly allocated widgets `delete`d in the class' destructor? I feel I'm missing something very important here...

Comment: "When QObjects are created on the heap (i.e., created with new), a tree can be constructed from them in any order, and later, the objects in the tree can be destroyed in any order. When any QObject in the tree is deleted, if the object has a parent, the destructor automatically removes the object from its parent. If the object has children, the destructor automatically deletes each child. No QObject is deleted twice, regardless of the order of destruction."
--> But in the example, the widgets added via `new` never get passed a `parent`...? E.g. part 1, definition of the labels

Comment: `setLayout` completes the tree.

Comment: So, in which scenario a `new`ly created widget would have to be `delete`d in the destructor?